# Tests for positive definiteness of nonsymmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Do tests for positive definiteness for nonsymmetric matrices exist?  More specifically I am working with bidiagonal upper/lower triangular matrices with positive eigenvalues and I need to check to see if they are positive definite or not.

Comment: if $(Ax,x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in V,$ then $A=A*$ provided you are working over complex numbers.

Comment: You can't start the question with "Do they exist". What are "they"? Make the question self-contained, and remember that a title is just an elevator pitch line to draw people and let them know what the question is about, in particular the title is not part of the question's text.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It will help us to better answer it if you give a more complete context for your question and share what you've tried so far.  Also, you may wish to follow the customary style used here; see the [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is real.  Note that $x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx$, being a scalar.  Hence $x^TAx>0$ if and only if $2x^TAx=x^TAx+x^TA^Tx=x^T(A+A^T)x>0$.  Thus $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A+A^T$, a symmetric matrix, is positive definite.  You can test this using the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

If $A$ is complex, replace $x^TAx$ with $x^\star Ax$ and $A^T$ with $A^\star$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used Sylvester's criterion on $A^\dagger + A$ to show that it was not positive definite.

Comment: @lowrybh, my pleasure.

Comment: In the complex case $A$ "positive definite" ($x^T Ax \gt 0$ for all $x$) implies that $A$ [must be Hermitian](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/473635/3111).