# Are positive definite matrices necessarily diagonalizable and when does the famous eigenvalue criterion apply?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I mean in $\mathbb{C}$ positive definite matrices seem to be self-adjoint. For matrices over real vector spaces this seems to be wrong, but is it still true that they are diagonalizable?

Then everyone knows a result similar to this: When a matrix has only positive eigenvalues then it is positive definite. Is this result always true, and do we also have the converse in general?

Comment: Many authors *mean* positive definite and symmetric (or self-adjoint) when they write simply positive definite.  It is symmetry which implies diagonalizable, so really this is a question about what you mean by positive definite.

Comment: ah, that explains a lot, since I was wondering about some passages in a book that I found on it, great remark, thanks, but NO I do not want the matrix to be necessarily symmetric

Comment: Also, a matrix is positive definite only if its eigenvalues are all positive. A symmetric matrix with only positive eigenvalues is positive definite.

Comment: @JonathanY.: You could of course define "positive definite" to mean that, but it is not a widely used definition. [See this Question and Answers.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4336/3111)

Comment: @hardmath, I believe I'm using the standard definition of "positive-definite" (correct me if I'm wrong). However, if a matrix has a non-positive eigenvalue, showing that it's not positive-definite is straightforward. A real symmetric matrix, on the other hand, is normal, hence it has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors; the road is paved to showing the other direction as well for this type of matrix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An extension of the definition of "positive definite" to non-symmetric (real) matrices is to require $v^T M v \gt 0$ for all suitable nonzero vectors $v$.  However see the discussion [on this older Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83134/3111) about the lack of a conventionally adopted definition.

For real matrices [this allows for non-self-adjoint (non-symmetric) examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non_symmetric_matrices).  However the analogous "extension" for complex matrices, $v^* M v \gt 0$ for all nonzero vectors, turns out to imply $M$ self-adjoint (Hermitian), so it gives "nothing new".

As far as *diagonalizability* goes, neither requiring all eigenvalues positive nor requiring positive definiteness in the sense given above is sufficient to imply similarity to a diagonal matrix.  Of course similar to a diagonal matrix would be *implied* by a full set of *distinct* eigenvalues (as each eigenvalue has at least one eigenvector), and it is *equivalent* to a basis of eigenvectors (since the matrix representation wrt to such basis is diagonal).

Here's an example of a nonsymmetric real matrix that (a) has only the positive eigenvalue 1 and (b) satisfies the "coercivity" condition $v^T M v \gt 0$ for all nonzero (real) vectors but (c) cannot be diagonalized:

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Note that if $v^T = (x \; y)$, then $v^T M v = x^2 + 0.1xy + y^2$, which is easily shown to be a positive definite *quadratic form*, and thus the second (stronger) notion of a positive definite (but nonsymmetric) real matrix holds.

Comment: Nice answer, just adding here thatt $M$ above does have a square root that's positive definite (but of course not symmetric), namely: $ sqrt(M) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.05 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $