# Closest symmetric matrix that satisfies linear inequality constraint

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, svd, projection

I want to find the closest symmetric matrix (using the Frobenius norm, or another matrix norm) to a given symmetric matrix $G$ such that the inner product with a given rank-$1$ matrix $b b^T$ is bigger than a given constant $c$.

Given $G \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ symmetric, $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\tilde{G}}{\text{minimize}} & \| \tilde{G} - G \|\\ \text{subject to} & b^T \tilde{G} \ b \geq c\end{array}$$

I think that there should be a relation with the PCA SVD and that somehow the answer should be related to the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $G$. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. it is symmetric

Comment: this can be phrased as a convex quadratic optimization problem; solving the unconstrained problem and the one with "$=c$" is simple using the KKT conditions.

Comment: You can make your life easier by minimizing $\| \tilde{G}-G\|_{F}^{2}$.  Also note that either $\tilde{G}=G$ will satisfy the constraint and be optimal, or the single linear constraint will be active at optimality.  Have you tried to write down the KKT conditions for this problem?

Comment: @LinAlg I could use KKT conditions but I'd like to find a general characterization of the solution of this problem. My guess is that I can do an eigendecomposition of the matrix G and move the eigvenvalues according to the weight induced by b, a bit like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648809/how-to-find-closest-positive-definite-matrix-of-non-symmetric-matrix

Comment: There is a simle formula that can be derived using the KKT conditions.

Comment: @BrianBorchers can u explain?